# Объясните следующую конструкцию

Tags: java, android, методы, android-intent

```
public class CheatActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
        mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
    }
}
```

а именно часть:

```
mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
```

Answer (score 6):

Activity можно стартануть через интент. К примеру:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
```

и метод `getIntent()` возвращает вам интент, которым была запущена данная активити.

Далее из интента достается булевая переменная по ключу `EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE`

Лучше всего вам объяснит [официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#java)

Answer (score 2):

**Немного теории:**

`Intent` - абстрактное описание выполняемой операции.

`Intent` часто в сети описывают как намерение, для выполнения операции. И это описание довольно удачно из-за того, что Intent мб явным и неявным.

Основные использование:

1. В startActivity для запуска Activity.
2. В broadcastIntent для отправки его любым заинтересованным компонентам BroadcastReceiver.
3. В startService (Intent) или в bindService (Intent, ServiceConnection, int) для связи с фоновым сервисом.

Наиболее значимое использование - это начало деятельности, где ее можно рассматривать как связь между действиями. Это в основном пассивная структура данных, содержащая абстрактное описание действия, которое необходимо выполнить.

Итог: `Intent` это сущность, которая позволяет связать компоненты приложений, имеет возможность управлять ими и при этом может передать данные между компонентами, что у вас в примере и происходит.

**Ответ:**

*Стартуем:*

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, mAnswerIsTrue);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Намерение запустить с текущего класса -> CheatActivity.

Положить в намерение intent (Bundle) по ключу  EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE (String) значение mAnswerIsTrue(boolean).

*Получаем:*

```
mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
```

Мы пытаемся получить переменную mAnswerIsTrue(bool).

Для этого мы получаем intent командой `getIntent`, достаем из intent(Bundle) командой `getBooleanExtra` бул переменную, в случае если ключ EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE не существует, то ставим ей дефолтное значение `false`.